# Запятая перед "кто"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика

Предложение: "Первый, кто приобрел популярность в этой семье, была Томирис"

Answer (score 3):

Только не ПЕРВЫЙ, а ПЕРВОЙ.

Первой, кто приобрел популярность в этой семье, была Томирис.

Предложение сложноподчинённое. ***...кто приобрёл популярность...*** — придаточное предложение с союзным словом — местоимением КТО. С подлежащим КТО в придаточном предложении используется сказуемое в форме единственного числа мужского рода.

Главное предложение — ***Первой ... была Томирис.***  *Была первой* — сказуемое в главном предложении.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая перед ***кто*** нужна, она отделяет придаточное предложение в составе сложного.

[**КТО**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x%5D)

> **II. союзн. сл. 1.** Присоединяет придаточное подлежащее. *Блажен, **кто** смолоду был молод* (Пушкин). **2.** Присоединяет придаточное определительное. *Вот и мой друг, **о ком** я много рассказывал.* **3.** Присоединяет придаточное дополнительное. *Все приветствовали того, **кто** вошёл первым. Думать надо, **кого** позвать.*

В приведённом предложении необходимо согласование:

*Перв**ым** [человеком], кто приобрел популярность в этой семье, была Томирис.*

или

*Перв**ой** [женщиной], кто приобрел популярность в этой семье, была Томирис.*